# split string in JS from slash

Tags: javascript

I have such kind string

```
someRandomCountCharacters/someRandomCountCharacters%someRandomCountCharacters
```

how can I get middle part? I mean I need get only from "/" to "%" string

Comment: What have you tried Vardan?

Comment: Instead of thinking in terms of splitting, think in terms of substringing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var str="someRandomCountCharacters/someRandomCountCharacters%someRandomCountCharacters";

var middle_string = str.split('/')[1].split('%')[0];